# Partial class not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, forms-authentication

I'm working on an intranet and have a long model that was generated by EntityFramework for my Employee Database, I wanted to divide the password from it, and since it's a partial class I figured I'd create this :

```
namespace CRAWebSiteMVC.Models
{
    public partial class Employee
    {
        public global::System.String Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _Password;
            }
            set
            {
                OnPasswordChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Password");                    
                ReportPropertyChanged("Password");
                OnPasswordChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _Password;
        partial void OnPasswordChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnPasswordChanged();

    }

}
```

But now, whenever I try to assign a value to password it always end up have a null value.

E.g :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Employee objEmployee, FormCollection form)
    {
        ViewBag.CompanyList = _service.ListCompany();
        ViewBag.SupervisorList = _service.ListSupervisor();

        objEmployee.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now; // They will get the good value
        objEmployee.UpdatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;

        objEmployee.Password = form["Password"]; // will always be = to null, even when the form is filled
    }
```

What can be the cause of this?

EDIT : Password now has a value, thank you all.

But now the following error occures :

```
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

At this point :

```
 public Employee Create(Employee objEmployee)
    {
        _entities.AddToEmployees(objEmployee);
        _entities.SaveChanges(); // Fails here
        return objEmployee;
    }
```

How can a SaveChange fail like that?

Comment: when debugging which one is null, is it `form["Password"]`?

Comment: No, form["Password"] catches the password, but objEmployee.Password is null.

Comment: Then, it's the setter of your Password property which doesn't hold it, as @kenam mentionned in his answer :)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but... where do you assign _Password ?

Comment: Editing to add a new question is prob not the best way to get help.. but anyway.. what info does the inner exception contain?
I prob wont be much more help as I don't know EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sample above I don't see where the field `_Password` is being set.  If none of the methods OnPasswordChanging, ReportPropertyChanging, ReportPropertyChanged or OnPasswordChanged do it - then set `_Password = value`.

i.e.

```
  set
        {
            OnPasswordChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Password");   
            _Password = value;
            ReportPropertyChanged("Password");
            OnPasswordChanged();
        }
```

Comment: You should really phrase this as a statement, rather than a question, to make it clear that you're providing an answer and not asking a clarifying question.